# ArrayFormula with GoogleFinance dynamic date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, google-finance

First of all, i'm not a powerful sheets user :)

I'm trying to use GOOGLEFINANCE to calculate amounts in multiple currencies.
I use this formula:

```
=IF($A2;
IF( 
$C2:C; 
$C2:C;
IF(
  $D2:D; 
  $D2:D*INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDUAH";"close";$A2);2;2);
  $E2:E*INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUAH";"close";$A2);2;2)
));
0)
```

A-column contains dates,
C,D,E - amounts in 3 different currencies.
IFs are just to prioritize columns :)

The formula works well but i need to "extend" it each time i add row - to increment 
$A2 -> $A3 to get rate for specified date.

I try to use ArrayFormula but it turns out it keeps reference to $A2 so i get same rate irrelevant from date specified in A-cells.

I have created sample sheet to illustrate:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K2TbGIWl7JacYKiWgwwmJfelxJ-7fa9F9obp5XswW18/edit?usp=sharing

I have allowed editing by anyone, so if you decide to edit - please don't remove anything :) also you can drop your username in sticky row(above your proposed solution)

1. Is there a way to apply ArrayFormula to this to make it work?
2. Maybe you can provide more readable solution to nested IFs.

Comment: What about changing `$A2` to `$A2:A`?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @ScottCraner it passes range to googlefinance, not sure it'll work as it expects single date.

Comment: @player0 updated question with link to sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>""; 
 IF(C2:C<>""; C2:C; 
 IF(D2:D<>""; VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A); 
 TO_TEXT(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDUAH"; 
 "close"; MIN(A:A); MAX(A:A)+1);
 "offset 1 format Col1'dd.mm.yy'"; 0)); 2; 0)*1; 
 VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A); 
 TO_TEXT(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUAH"; 
 "close"; MIN(A:A); MAX(A:A)+1);
 "offset 1 format Col1'dd.mm.yy'"; 0)); 2; 0)*1)); ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: cool!
looks like it works, but it's really hard to understand what it does :)
one more follow-up: can i make it multiply googlefinance result on corresponding currency cell value?
(i have updated **dragging** column formula)

Comment: sure, use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>""; 
 IF(C2:C<>""; C2:C; 
 IF(D2:D<>""; D2:D*VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A); 
 TO_TEXT(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDUAH"; 
 "close"; MIN(A:A); MAX(A:A)+1);
 "offset 1 format Col1'dd.mm.yy'"; 0)); 2; 0)*1; 
 E2:E*VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A); 
 TO_TEXT(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUAH"; 
 "close"; MIN(A:A); MAX(A:A)+1);
 "offset 1 format Col1'dd.mm.yy'"; 0)); 2; 0)*1)); ))`

Answer (score 0):

There is a new simpler and more flexible method now since the introduction of `LAMBDA` and its helper functions in Google Sheets in August 2022.

Assuming dates in A2:A, and amounts in UAH, USD, EUR in C2:C, D2:D, E2:E respectively, then the following formula will work, e.g. in cell F2:

```
=MAP(A2:A;C2:C;D2:D;E2:E;
    LAMBDA(date;uah;usd;eur;
        IFS(
        uah;uah;
        usd;usd*INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:usduah";"price";date);2;2);
        eur;eur*INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:euruah";"price";date);2;2);
        ISBLANK(date);)))
```

The trick here is that `MAP(LAMBDA)` calculates the specified formula for each row of the input array separately (effect similar to manually expanding the formula over the whole range), whereas `ARRAYFORMULA` passes the whole array as an argument to the formula (`GOOGLEFINANCE` is special and doesn't work intuitively with such input).

This general method with `MAP(LAMBDA)` can now be used to pass any arguments to `GOOGLEFINANCE` in a way one would otherwise expect to do with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Answer (score -1):

Try This One:

```
=arrayformula(
   IF(query(arrayformula(if(A2:A="",False,True)), 
      "Select * where Col1=True"),
      IF( $C2:C, 
          $C2:C,
          IF( $D2:D,   
              $D2:D*INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDUAH","close",$A2),2,2),  
              $E2:E*INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUAH","close",$A2),2,2))),0))
```

Comment: this one generally works, but it always uses rate for date in $A2.

Comment: Please try to change ", $A2)" to  ", $A2:A)"

Comment: i tried but it does differ from what i get when directly referencing cell from A.I have added spreadsheet link for demo in question

Comment: the main problem with GoogleFinance function is that you can't do "A2:A" in the date, there are numerous questions about it...
it make this solution incorrect