# Cannot properly array googlefinance formula with dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

I am trying to convert money amounts in USD to EUR, but I want to do it in relation to date of transaction taking place due to dyncamic exchange rates.

Idea is to use `googlefinance` function with `index` function, along with `date` function, which will be made of `right`, `mid`, and `left` functions. All of that should be wrapped with `arrayformula`. Numbers should be rounded using `round`.

**Non-working example:**

[image]

Don't mind `;`, this is instead of `,` in my google sheets language settings.

**Formula:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";"";ROUND(INDEX(B2:B*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR";"price";DATE(RIGHT(A2:A;4);MID(A2:A;4;2);LEFT(A2:A;2)));2;2);2)))`

**Formula** (with `,` instead of `;`):
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="","",ROUND(INDEX(B2:B*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR","price",DATE(RIGHT(A2:A,4),MID(A2:A,4,2),LEFT(A2:A,2))),2,2),2)))`

Since I'm pretty sure this formula should work in "normal circumstances", I've replicated it leaving out arrayformula, and full ranges (such as B2:B, etc), and it works once I drag down the formula.

**Working example:**
[image]

**Formula:** `=IF(F2="";"";ROUND(INDEX(F2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR";"price";DATE(RIGHT(E2;4);MID(E2;4;2);LEFT(E2;2)));2;2);2))`

**Formula** (with `,` instead of `;`):
`=IF(F2="","",ROUND(INDEX(F2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR","price",DATE(RIGHT(E2,4),MID(E2,4,2),LEFT(E2,2))),2,2),2))`

**Does anyone have idea what's going on with the first case, i.e. why it doesn't work?** I believe it has to be something with those full ranges (e.g. B2:B, A2:B, etc), but not sure why...

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CgpCRyjFTiDspEFLDJtqxZQI-a7SH3ELhQztvGfywLs/edit?usp=sharing

There you go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayFormula with GoogleFinance dynamic date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273160/arrayformula-with-googlefinance-dynamic-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GOOGLEFINANCE` is already an `ARRAYFORMULA` type formula so try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;ROUND(B2:B*IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A+0,9986111111; 
 GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDEUR"; "price"; MIN(A2:A); MAX(A2:A)+1); 2; 1)); 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: :) Wiat, how. I only got zeros. You can see here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CgpCRyjFTiDspEFLDJtqxZQI-a7SH3ELhQztvGfywLs/edit#gid=0

It also says "VLOOKUP only takes 4 arguments, but this is argument 5".

Comment: you changed semicolon to comma instead of dot in number 0,9986111111 (should be: 0.9986111111 - if you use commas instead of semicolons) see your sheet

Comment: :O magic. Thank you very much.

Btw, if you find time, would you please shortly describe what are you doing, since I really don't understand how formula does what it does.

For example, what is IFNA, what is 0.9986111111 (i googled it, i says it is 1438 minutes, which is almost one day, but why :D). Also how does this vlookup works at all, it looks nothing like vlookup i'm used to... :D

Comment: if VLOOKUP does not find any value it will produce #N/A error. to remove this error from output we use IFNA around VLOOKUP so if value is not found it will output empty row. 0.9986111111 is indeed time "23:58:00". if you run just GOOGLEFINANCE formula you can notice that first column includes date and also time but your A column consists only from dates. (keep in mind that dates are just formated numbers so date 09.07.2020 = 44021 but 09.07.2020 23:58:00 = 44021.9986111111) so the idea is to add "23:58:00" to your dates in A column and then pair it via VLOOKUP with GOOGLEFINANCE timestamps

Comment: This makes sense to me now. Thank you very much!